# How to disable javascript when loading a webpage with python, without using selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, python-requests

I manage a web scraping project which scrapes from websites with no javascript, in which case I use the requests library, and websites with javascript, in which case I use Selenium and Chromedriver. However Selenium is very slow, and I believe the javascript websites have 'javascript disabled' versions of their webpages, which contain all the data I need. how can I load the 'javascript disabled' version of the webpage without using Selenium?

This is one of the websites: https://www.sainsburys.co.uk/shop/gb/groceries

For example, I want to extract all products from the following page:

https://www.sainsburys.co.uk/shop/gb/groceries/bakery/all-cakes---tarts#langId=44&storeId=10151&catalogId=10123&categoryId=340930&parent_category_rn=12320&top_category=12320&pageSize=36&orderBy=FAVOURITES_ONLY%7CSEQUENCING%7CTOP_SELLERS&searchTerm=&beginIndex=0

To do this, I use the xpath "//div[@id='productLister']/ul[contains(@class, 'productLister')]/li/div[contains(@class, 'product')]"

If you load the page in your browser with Javascript, this selector works with no issue.

If you disable javascript on the webpage using a browser extension (I use Quick Javascript Switcher for Chrome), you can see that the products still load, and you can still use the selector. This means that Sainsbury's has a 'javascript disabled' version of the webpage, which still contains all the data I need.

However, if I try and use requests and this xpath to extract the data, it doesn't work.

Comment: If you get all data without javascript, can't you just use requests.

Comment: If I use requests, it will return the html for the javascript enabled webpage, but it won't have any info because the javascript won't have loaded